# JavaScript editing the URL like facebooks rewriting without hash #

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, hash, url-rewriting

You have to use a hash to edit the url in anyway, but how can facebook not use the hash and still change the url?

So i am in the process of writing a new photo gallery. I need to be able to perm link each photo, whilst obviously changing the image.

My thoughts were hash with the url, so if the hash is removed its still a perm link eg:

```
#?pid=1212918
```

Then i thought let me check to see how facebook are doing it and to my shock horror they aren't using hash's and still rewriting everything :O

Anyway, does anybody know how this can be done yet?

[edit] Upon looking on ie (non html5, at least patically) i see they are still using the hash. So they are using a rewrite server side if somebody accesses the site with a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with more research and the help of this question :P. The answer:

You can only do this with HTML5, so only new browsers will support this. Look at PushState/ReplaceState/PopState and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history For a HTML5 and HTML4 compatible project that supports this HTML5 State Functionality check out https://github.com/browserstate/History.js :-)